# Understanding the definition for an n times differentiable function at a point

Tags: real-analysis

From my lectures notes I have that a function $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is $n$ times differentiable at $x_0\in(a,b)$ if $f$ is $n-1$ times differentiable on a neighbourhood of $x_0$, and $f(n−1)$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

But I am unsure on the motivation as to why we need $f$ to be $n-1$ times differentiable on a neighbourhood of $x_0$ rather than just at the point $x_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to think about the limit definition of the $n$'th derivative:
$$
f^{(n)}(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x_0+h)-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)}{h}
$$
For the above limit to make sense, we need $f^{(n-1)}(x)$ to make sense in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: [Does $(k+1)$-times differentiable at a point imply $k$-times differentiable in interval? What about continuously?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275772/does-k1-times-differentiable-at-a-point-imply-k-times-differentiable-in-i) operatorerror, please help here